# Powershell Access denied localhost as Administrator

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script which has been installing our software for years on our servers. Since a while we have a new server, which as far as we can check is a duplicate of an older one. 
We have a script:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $appServer -ScriptBlock $ConfigureServer 
Where $appServer = localhost
```

this command works on all the other servers but on the new one we get Access Denied. We have tried things as `Enable-PSRemoting -Force`. We also start Powershell as administrotor. We have been stuck on this for days.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: What does the error say exactly? I had an error "Access was denied to user location information" and it was because I had win 10 location setting turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, have you ran `Test-WSMan` to see if the server is listening to remoting commands?

If this does return fine, can you check the execution policy on the machine? Try running `Set-ExectionPolicy unrestricted` and see if the script then runs?

Comment: Thank you for your response. We just tried this, but without any luck.